# Unity3d c# - Variable visible in inspector but not for other classes

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible in Unity3d to make a variable visible in the inspector but not to other classes. I want the variable to be private to other classes but it still needs to be set in the inspector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this using [SerializeField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html?_ga=1.196855467.646980666.1482614025):

For **C#**:

```
[SerializeField] private Type name;
```

For **JavaScript**:

```
@SerializeField
private var name : Type;
```

Looks like Unity even has a [short video tutorial](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/tips/show-private-variables-inspector) on this topic.

Comment: You are THE BEST! Thank you!